# Combine nomenclature entries without destroying layout

Tags: nomenclature

I am trying to generate a nomenclature for all symbols used in my thesis. Some variables having the same indices should be grouped as they belong together. However, when I try to group them, the lay-out of the nomenclature gets all messed up. See below MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}

% create the lsymb command
\newcommand{\lsymb}[2]{#1\nomenclature[b ]{#1}{\MakeUppercase#2}}

% make the nomenclature
\makenomenclature
\makeindex


\begin{document}
I would like to have the variables \lsymb{$a_f$, $b_f$, $c_f$ and $d_f$}{The variables I am trying to group} group on two lines in the nomenclature.

However, when I add more variables such as \lsymb{$a_b$}{another variable} and \lsymb{$c_f$}{yet another variable}, the lay-out gets quite messy.

I could try grouping the variables, like I did with \lsymb{$d_a$, $e_a$,}{a group of variables}\lsymb{$g_a$, and $h_a$}{{}}. But that grouping order will be broken if a variable \lsymb{$f$}{some annoying variable} were to come along.

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image: text]
[image: corresponding nomenclature]

So what basically happens, is:

- Grouping the variables in a single group distorts the lay-out
- Splitting the variables across multiple lines gets messed up by the automatic alphabetic ordering (which I wish to keep).

Solutions I am looking for:

- widen the column containing the variables, so that all descriptions are aligned
- somehow make the grouped variables into a multiline object, so other variables can't mess up the sorting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could leave away the "and". Is the sorting done automatically? If not, just add `\lsymb{$c_f$, and $d_f$}{}` as a second line.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: yes, the sorting is done automatically. Perhaps I could add a phantom letter in front of the second part though, will try it out and report back.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I have tried splitting the entries and it works thus far, however the automatic sorting is likely to break this solution later on as I add more variables. I'll work on adding a MWE, but since the custom class I use is quite complex it is taking some time.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I've added the MWE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the optional argument, which is a length, when calling `\printnomenclature`, e.g.

```
\printnomenclature[3cm]
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}

% create the lsymb command
\newcommand{\lsymb}[2]{#1\nomenclature[b ]{#1}{\MakeUppercase#2}}

% make the nomenclature
\makenomenclature
\makeindex


\begin{document}
I would like to have the variables \lsymb{$a_f$, $b_f$, $c_f$ and $d_f$}{The variables I am trying to group} group on two lines in the nomenclature.

However, when I add more variables such as \lsymb{$a_b$}{another variable} and \lsymb{$c_f$}{yet another variable}, the lay-out gets quite messy.

I could try grouping the variables, like I did with \lsymb{$d_a$, $e_a$,}{a group of variables}\lsymb{$g_a$, and $h_a$}{{}}. But that grouping order will be broken if a variable \lsymb{$f$}{some annoying variable} were to come along.

\printnomenclature[3cm]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @WouterKuijsters You're welcome :)